# Sketchflow Silverlight - Change button's border

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, sketchflow

I am using Expression Blend.

I have a sketch button and the button's border looks sketchy and wavy. Is there a method how to change the border to a solid line without deleting the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a style on the button. When you're doing a Sketchflow project, the default styles are defined in the SketchStyles.xaml `ResourceDictionary` When you add the button to your view, there should be something along the lines of `Style="{DynamicResource Button-Sketch}"` added to the line. Just remove that and your button's style is gone. You can create a custom style to make the button look the way you want.

If you're spending time styling your view, why are you using SketchFlow? The idea behind it is to quickly prototype your views. It's not meant to be your final product.

Comment: This answer is correct (I work on the SketchFlow team at Microsoft).